# akka-http. Generate file and send to client

Tags: scala, akka-http

I need to save string to the text file and send to browser. My route:

```
def genFileRoute: Route =
    path("someresource" / "generate") {
        get {
            complete( genFile )
        }
    }
```

But i have a problem with generator:

```
def genFile = {
    val str = "Hi all! I am a string in future text file"

     // Need to write some code here :(
     // Something like 'php://output' with headers, but for akka.
}
```

How to create in-memory text file `file.txt`, without using file system? How to send it to clients browser(download)?

**P.S.** Sorry for my English, it's not my native.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header for this - it allows you to set the file name sent to browser. No need to create a file at all; in your example, the function can return a plain String.

```
def genFile = {
    val str = "Hi all! I am a string in future text file"

    str
}
```

Route:

```
path("someresource" / "generate") {
  get {
    respondWithHeader(`Content-Disposition`(
        ContentDispositionTypes.attachment, Map("filename" -> "somefile.txt"))) {
      complete(genFile)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: for future souls: `import akka.http.scaladsl.model.headers._`